# How to move Google Map to where the mark was added

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Hey guys I'm using the Google Maps API on my project but the problem is that when I add a mark, the map doesn't move to where the mark is. The mark is getting added but it's not visible if you don't zoom out and go where it is.

Any tip on how I can achieve that?

```
let myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
     zoom: 8
});
```

and this is the adding a mark:

```
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: {
         lat: 37.7749,
         lng: 122.4194
     },
     map: myMap,
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why don't you `center` the map at the marker's coordinates?

Comment: I tried using the `myMap.center = { lat: 37.7749,  lng: 122.4194}` but it doesn't work. Is there another way to do that? Also, I will have multiple marks on the screen it would be great if they could be centered.

Comment: You need [.setCenter()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setCenter). Still, how exactly do you want this to work? You currently initialize the map centered at `lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644`; why not replace that with the actual coordinates you want as your center? If that's not enough, please clarify your question.

Comment: @ChrisG the `setCenter()` works. Thank you! In the beginning there will not be anything on the map, that's why I'm using a random position. The users will query whatever they want and then I'll get an array of coordinates to add the marks on the map. But it would be great if I could always show all those points in the map.

Comment: I see, in that case you need to calculate the minimum and maximum of all lats and lngs, then add them and divide by 2; this gives the center of multiple markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works for me:

```
   addMarker(position: google.maps.LatLng) {
        if (this.marker) {
            this.marker.setMap(null);
        }
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position,
            map: this.map,
            draggable: true,
            clickable: true,
            // icon: 'assets/images/favicon.png',
        });
        this.marker.setVisible(true);
    }
```

To center the map you may do that:

```
 setCenter(lat: number, lng: number) {
        this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    }
```

Comment: Note: If the map is set to null, the marker will be removed.
Then you can add a new one and then set it visible.

Comment: Hey @Amr Omar yeah, it was the `setCenter` method. Thanks man